# Removing the colon from 24 hrs format time in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I need to resolve an issue that has been bugging my bug list for a while but can't find anything solid in Google. All I want is to remove the colon from the time so I can display it in REAL military time.

So, this is wrong --> 13:25 hrs
This is right -->     1325 hrs

I am using Jquery Date Picker form the Jquery UI library and `datetimepicker-addon.js` from [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="my_date" id="my_date" value="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){   
    $("#my_date").datetimepicker({
       timeFormat: "HH:mm 'hrs'",
       showButtonPanel: false
    });
});
```

Here is a handy dandy **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/bwAXqk)**

I appreciate the help

Comment: `timeFormat: "HHmm 'hrs'",` simply remove the colon from the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `timeFormat` of the `datetimepicker` remove the colon

```js
$(function(){
 // when the document has loaded 
 // attach the datetimepicker
 $("#my_date").datetimepicker({
  timeFormat: "HHmm 'hrs'",
  showButtonPanel: false
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<div class="container">
 <input type="text" name="my_date" id="my_date" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA I should kick myself in the face! Why do I overthink everything so much? HAHAHA